# How to order column depending on screen size?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to do the following layout for medium screen size

```
<div class="col-md-12">A</div>
<div class="col-md-12">B</div>
<div class="col-md-12">C</div>

[A-12]
[B-12]
[C-12]
```

I want to do the following layout for large screen size

```
<div class="col-lg-9>A</div>
<div class="col-lg-3>C</div>
<div class="col-lg-9>B</div>

[A-9][C-3]
[B-9]
```

I'm doing my smaller screen design first (since it's supposed to be mobile first right?) then I'm trying to push/pull B and C to put C right next to A. But it's not working.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-9">A</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-9 col-lg-push-3">B</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-9">C</div>

//Expected result
[A-9][C-3]
[B-9]

//Result I'm getting
[A-9]
[C-3][B-9]
```

So, how should I do my layout to get the expected result?

Comment: Try adding `.col-md-push-0` to the `.col-lg-push-*` divs.

Comment: the question is not clear. By only using your fist code (only the col-lg) you'll get that behavior you want. I don't know why you want a col-9 below, so you should explain what happens with that 3-col empty space and how do you want to deal with that col-9 (you mention push/pull, which are total opposites). Still, I'm sure it's totally easy, just not getting it from your explanation. And I think you're confusing how BS works, as we're at it, check the grids doc like @isherwood mentions

Comment: @TheLittlePig's answer is right. Forget push/pull for this purpose (and most purposes). They really only move things laterally, not up and down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is something like I suppose you want :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/zu6yDOeHwn

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-9">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 ">A</div>
         <div class="col-md-12">B</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-3">C</div>
</div>
```